# Tkinter - Storing folder directory in function and calling it to change directory

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system

I am trying to develop a GUI with tkinter. I have created a function (as a button) to browse for a directory folder ('input folder'). I have a routine linked to another button ('execute') that needs the path from 'input folder'.

I am getting errors when I try to pass the path from 'input folder' into os.chdir inside 'execute'. Example is as follows:

```
import sys
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def Input():
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    global filename

def Extraction():
    in_loc = filename
    os.chdir(in_loc)

btn = Button(window, text="Extract", bg="black", fg="white", command=Extraction)
btn.pack()

btn2 = Button(text="Input", command=Input).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Can anyone reproduce this and tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

filename = ''


def input_function():
    global filename

    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()


def extraction():
    global filename

    in_loc = filename
    os.chdir(in_loc)


window = Tk()

btn = Button(window, text="Extract", bg="black", fg="white", command=extraction)
btn.pack()

btn2 = Button(text="Input", command=input_function).pack()

window.mainloop()
```